# prestashop webservices for image in json format

Tags: json, xml, web-services

When I parse image data using prestashop webservices in XML format it works fine, but when I change the output format to JSON it is getting an error.

**In XML format result is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image_types>
        <image_type id="7" name="category_default" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/image_types/7"/>
        <image_type id="3" name="medium_default" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/image_types/3"/>
    </image_types>
    <images>
        <image id="10" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/10"/>
        <image id="11" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/11"/>
        <image id="3" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/3"/>
        <image id="4" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/4"/>
        <image id="5" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/5"/>
        <image id="6" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/6"/>
        <image id="7" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/7"/>
        <image id="8" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/8"/>
        <image id="9" xlink:href="http://abcd.com/api/images/categories/9"/>
    </images>
</prestashop>
```

**in JSON format result is**

```
{"":[{"id":"7"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"10"},{"id":"11"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"7"},{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"}],"errors":[{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."},{"code":null,"message":"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."}]}
```

Comment: I also see this same issue when getting the images in JSON vs XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to get image from prestashop web services

```
 <img src="http://abcd.com/api/images/products/{{product_id}}/{{image_id}}?ws_key=DS2FHJQQQSAG381PB52237254DVK9R14">
```

and get your product id and image id from you product list file xml/json.
put that id's on that image url and you get your get image